# Turn off Bluetooth in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I want to turn off the Bluetooth Adapter in Windows as it sometimes interferes with another device.

I am using python 3.6 and PyQt5 in Windows.

I have tried stopping the service using.

`net stop bthserv /y`

This only stops the service but does not turn off the bluetooth in the control panel or taskbar

[image]

Is there anyway I can turn this off either using the commandline in windows or using Python/PyQt5?

```
from subprocess import TimeoutExpired, Popen, run, call, check_output, STARTUPINFO, STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, SW_HIDE, PIPE, STDOUT

class BT:
    def process_f(self, command, bsize=4096):

        print('1a) Process started...')

        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE

        p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
                startupinfo=startupinfo, bufsize=bsize, universal_newlines=True)
        try:
            out, err = p.communicate(timeout=300)            
        except TimeoutExpired:
            p.kill()            
            out, err = p.communicate()
        return out.split(), err.split()

    def service_switch(self, service, on=False, off=False):
        """ Start or stop a service in windows """

        if on:
            switch = 'start'
        elif off:
            switch = 'stop'
        else:
            return False

        command = 'net {} {} /y'.format(switch, service)

        p = self.process_f(command)

        out, err = p[0], p[1]

        print('STDOUT: {}'.format(out))
        print('STDERR: {}'.format(err))

bt = BT()

bt.service_switch('bthserv', on=True)
# bt.service_switch('bthserv', off=True)
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/922293/python-script-that-turns-bluetooth-on-and-off

Comment: Thanks but this is in windows

Comment: It's still related. If you can turn off Bluetooth in the command line using Windows, then you can do the same in Python using `os.system` or `subprocess.call`

Comment: Yes it is related, but I have already tried it.,  I have posted teh class i wrote to try and do this..

Comment: There are few ways. I do not know Python and can not provide code, but. You can use Service Manager API to turn service Off as it net command does. You can use Setup API to disable WiFi driver (there is good devcon demo application from MS) and finally you can use WinRT API to turn WiFi Off as it Windows does by WiFi button.